GDAL having issues converting binary .DAT files to GeoTIFF files
I've been trying to convert some SNODAS Unmasked data from the National Snow and Ice Data Center using their guide linked here: https://nsidc.org/data/user-resources/help-center/how-do-i-convert-snodas-binary-files-geotiff-or-netcdf
I've been trying to convert these files to GeoTIFFs using the steps mentioned in the above-linked guide, but every time I run the command in OSGeo4w it returns an error. If I plug the command into OSGeo4w directly as it is stated in the guide (including my input/output files, of course), it will return the following error:
ERROR 6: Too many command options '+no_defs''

If I edit the command, it will either return the same error just with a different section of the command listed instead of '+no_defs'', or it will tell me that my input file is not a valid source (I have completely unzipped and untarred it, it is a regular .DAT file).

Sounds like an error with your command syntax, potentially.  It would help if you edited the question to include the exact command that's producing the error

Use -a_srs EPSG:4326 as suggested in the link you provided.

The tutorial is using single quotation marks for enclosing the proj string
-a_srs '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' 

On Windows you must use double quotes
-a_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

